# NamedRange referring to another Named Range

Tags: excel

Let's say I have two named ranges:

- `LEFT=A1:C4`
- `RIGHT=X1:X5`

Can a named range refer to other named ranges? Or does the named range evaluate to whatever cells it refers to at runtime? In other words, if I were to select both of the above ranges and try and do:

- `ALL=LEFT,RIGHT`

The runtime evaluation would be:

- `ALL=A1:C4,X1:x5`

Or how exactly would this work, and can named ranges refer to previously-defined named ranges, i.e., be indirectly or recursively defined?

Comment: What is the end goal of `ALL`?

Comment: Did you try it? It works for me exactly as you described it.

Comment: @BigBen to be a range that is the union of the `LEFT` range and `RIGHT` range.

Comment: @Enigmativity how did you set the range for `ALL` ? In a modal or programatically or would you want to show a screenshot or something of where/how you did that?

Comment: What kind of calculations are wanting to do?

Comment: Defined Names can refer to Defined Names which can refer to Defined Names ... In older versions of Excel it was possible to crash Excel by defining a circular loop of Defined Names, but this has been fixed in Excel 365 when LAMBDA was introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me exactly as you described it.

[image: Name Manager]

Comment: thanks for this. Now if you update the Apple range to refer to a new range, does the Cherry still work the same?

Comment: Yes, it does. I just tried it.